# Xpath - How to select parent based on attribute of child?

Tags: select, xpath, attributes, parent

How do you select a parent based on the attribute of a child?

I want to select a div:

```
//*[@id='outer']/div/div/div/div
```

that has a child with the 'a href' attribute equal to 'www.blah.com':

```
//*[@id='outer']/div/div/div/div/a[@href='www.blah.com']
```

Answer (score 19):

The basic fact you need is that predicates can be nested:-

```
//*[@id='outer']/div/div/div/div[a[@href='www.blah.com']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//*[@id='outer']/div/div/div/div/a[@href='www.blah.com']/../
```

Comment: on libxslt this is quite slow :/

Comment: using DOMXPath in PHP, that final `/` had to be removed - make sense?